# field of definition of abelian varieties with extra endormorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, complex-multiplication

Let $A$ be a complex abelian variety such that $\mathrm{End}(A)$ is strictly bigger than $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Question**: Is is true that $A$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

This is of course what happens for elliptic curves.

Comment: Dear Vima, Not in general, no.  E.g. if $E$ is a fixed CM elliptic curve, and $E'$ is an arbitrary elliptic curve (e.g. one one not defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$), then $E\times E'$ is an abelian variety not defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, with extra endomorphisms.  There are also many less trivial examples than this of positive dimensional families of ab. vars. with extra endomorphisms.  (These are basically what PEL-type Shimura varieties are.) Regards,

Comment: So under which conditions is that true? Is that the case if $End(A) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$ is a CM field of degree twice the dimension?